# How to access specific columns from a csv file in Powershell

Tags: csv, powershell, pipeline

I have imported a csv file to a variable `$diskuse`. `Csv` file has 2 columns.

I selected some rows based on a condition. How to pipeline 2nd column from selected elemets. This code is not working.

```
 $column=$diskuse | where($diskuse.UTILIZATION -lt 50)|Select-object @{Name='UTILIZATION';Expression={$_.Values[0]}}
echo $column
```

Answer (score 0):

This works!!

```
  $column=$diskuse |Where-Object {$_.UTILIZATION -lt 50}|Select-object @{Name='UTILIZATION';Expression={$_.UTILIZATION}}
    echo $column
```